# Controlling effect of ionic in layout

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework

Good night folks!

I have a layout problem, in my "Home" page when I click on the "About" runs an effect that glides to the left, and the "About" page is called. The problem is that when this effect occurs it goes over the side menu, and it should pass under the side menu.
 The idea is to let this fixed side menu, and screen center will be loaded content, following the concept of "Master Page".
 One option I found was to create effects in css, but it was not so "fast" and "natural" as the effects of ionic.

Note: To navigate between pages'm using routes scheme ionic

Full Project: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ei1jlr9pqam64rb/test2.rar?dl=0

For emulate on browser i use Ripple Emulate

Can anyone help me with this?

**Thank you for sharing your knowledge!**

[image]

Initial Code:

```
<body ng-app="app" animation="slide-left-right-ios7">
<div style="background-color: blue; margin-top: 50px; float: left; width: 50px; z-index: 2;">
    <h3>Menu</h3>
</div>

<div style="float: left; z-index: 1;">
    <div>
        <ion-nav-bar class="bar-stable">
            <ion-nav-back-button class="button-icon icon ion-ios-arrow-back">Back</ion-nav-back-button>
        </ion-nav-bar>

        <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add a starting point in code via a JSFiddle or CodePen, not via Dropbox or a screenshot. See also http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Yes, agree with Roy and then we could help you easier.